# How to implement a function that triggers an push notification when a new document is created on fcm?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

i have an university project that i'm developing an app that needs to receive a push notification when a new document is created on the collection 'ocorrencia' from firebase.

I've tried doing this firebase cloud function but without luck it doesn't work and i don't know how do i read the property token(my app sends the actual device token) from every user in 'admin' collection and add it to an array for sending it to all the devices with this value.

I've also tried using this tutorial but it didn't worked too:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-native-with-firebase-fcm-push-notifications-ios-android/

Here is my index.js function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.notificacao = functions.firestore
    .document('ocorrencia/{ocorrenciaId}')
    .onCreate((snap,context) => {

        const data = snap.data();
        const idAdmin = data.idAdmin

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title:'Nova Ocorrência',
                body:'Uma nova Ocorrência foi registrada'
            }
        }
        var pushToken = "";
        return functions
        .firestore
          .collection("admin/idAdmin")
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            pushToken = doc.data().token;
            return admin.messaging().sendTodevice(pushToken, payload)
          });
    })
```

And here are my app function that sends the token to the server(it's triggered after the user login):

```
async getDeviceToken(){
    let token;
    token = await this.fcm.getToken();
    console.log(this.adminUid);
    return this.sendFirestoreToken(token);
  }

  getAdminUid(){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      this.adminUid = auth.uid;
    })
  }

  sendFirestoreToken(token){
    const adminRef = this.afs.collection('admin')
    return adminRef.doc(this.adminUid).update({idAdmin: this.adminUid, token: token});
  }
```

Also there's my app repo on github here:
https://github.com/gianveloxbr/MacacoIrmaoADM/tree/master/macacoIrmao

The function needs to trigger everytime a new registry is added to 'ocorrencia' and it needs to be sended to every user in 'admin' collection with the property token on it.

**EDIT:**
I've tried this code but don't know how could i recover all the documents by their id

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.notificacao = functions.firestore
    .document('ocorrencia/{ocorrenciaId}')
    .onCreate((snap,context) => {

        const data = snap.data();
        const idAdmin = data.context.idAdmin


          const db = admin.firestore()

          // send a notification to each device token

          return Promise.all([admin.database().ref('admin/${}/token').once('value')]).then(
           // Don't know how to get every document using ${}
   results => {
                  const token = results[1];
                  if(!token.hasChildren()) return null;
                  let payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title:'Nova Ocorrência',
                        body:'Uma nova Ocorrência foi registrada'
                    }
                }
                const tokens = Object.keys(token.val());
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,payload);
              }
          )
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself by changing from token to topic:

**Here is the code if anyone wants to implement:**

index.js

```
exports.notificacao = functions.firestore
.document('ocorrencia/{ocorrenciaId}')
.onCreate((snap,context) => {
 let payload = {
      notification: {
          title: 'Nova ocorrência',
          body: 'Uma nova ocorrência foi registrada.',
          click_action: 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY'
      }
  }
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("admin",payload).then(response => {
          console.log('Notificação enviada com sucesso.', response);
      }).catch(error => {
          console.log('Erro:', error);
      })
    }
)
```

And for subscribing to a topic after the user is logged you need to implement this at app.component.ts

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
constructor(private fcm:FCM) { }
this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('admin');
```